# Результат шифрования имеет больший размер в байтах чем указывалось

Tags: c#, шифрование, криптография

Реализовываю шифрование 3DES на C#. Код:

```
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

tdes.Key = keyArray;

tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

tdes.FeedbackSize = 8;//+

ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();

byte[] resultArray =
  cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0,
  toEncryptArray.Length ); 
        tdes.Clear();

return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
```

Тут четко указывается, что размер в байтах должен быть **8 байтов**, у меня же **16** байтов `resultArray.Length = 16`. Размер входных данных для шифрования: **16** байт.

Ключ шифрования у меня имеет размер **16** байтов. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно получить **на выходе массив из 8 байт** и возможно ли такое в ключом в 16 байт?

Comment: А `FeedbackSize` разве не в битах указывается? Смотри [доки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx): `FeedbackSize - Получает или задает размер порции данных обратной связи для криптографической операции (в битах). (Унаследовано от SymmetricAlgorithm.)`

Comment: @BOPOH, даже если в битах,  и 1 байт=8 бит все равно не работает.

Comment: Размер входных данных в байтах укажите.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов  размер входных данных: 16 байт

Comment: Из 16 байт вы 16 байт и получаете, все в порядке. Не вижу явного указания в TransformFinalBlock на шифрование 8 байт.

Comment: Вы просто не понимаете как это работает. Вот [почитайте](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DES#.D0.91.D0.BB.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_.D1.88.D0.B8.D1.84.D1.80): на входе блок размером n бит, на выходе получается зашифрованный блок размером n бит. 3DES - это 3 раза DES, т.е. размер никакой не меняется

Comment: Неизменность размера справедлива для полных блоков. Неполные блоки в зависимости от могут расширяться до полных, соответственно размер данных может увеличиваться.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов,  я пробовал играться с числами в TransformFinalBlock, но к успеху это не привело. Как здесь указать , что мы хотим результат в виде 8и байт информации?

Comment: Начните с чтения документации по ICryptoTransform

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,  а здесь разве не полный блок? И вы сами заметили: дополнение до полного приведет только к увеличению размера, а не к уменьшению.

Comment: Я к тому что не обязательно размер выходных данных будет равен размеру входных. 16 байт в данном случае - 2 блока и расширения не должно быть, да.

Comment: @ BOPOH, спасибо за ссылку. Согласно статье, я не могу получить на выходе массив  меньший, чем входящий.

Comment: @BOPOH оформите в виде ответа?

Comment: В общем про массив вы не совсем правы: вы можете иметь массив в программе хоть 1024 байта, но шифровать при этом из него можете 8 байт. И получите 8 зашифрованных байт.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, другими словами - чтобы получить результат в 8 байт, ключ и сообщение должны быть длинною в 8 байт. Я вас верно понял?

Comment: Блок шифра (от вас он не зависит) и размер шифруемых данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение 8 байт зашифрованных данных в данном случае, скорее всего, получается путем указания верной длины шифруемых данных в вызове cTransform.TransformFinalBlock()

Comment: byte[] resultArray =
              cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0,
              toEncryptArray.Length -8) - на выходе массив из 8 байтов, как я и хотел, спасибо. Качество шифрования от этого не пострадало?

Comment: Вы шифруете не 8 байт, а на 8 байт меньше, чем было в массиве. Для массива в 128 байт результат будет несколько неожиданным :-) Качество шифрования тех самых 8 байт скорее страдает из-за длины ключа:3DES требует 3 ключа по 8 байт.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае правильнее было шифровать так:

```
var t = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
t.TransformBlock(MSG, 0, MSG.Length, RESULT, 0);
```

На выходе будет 8 байт.